# Sticky horizontal scrollview android

Tags: android, scrollview, sticky

i want create sticky horizontal scroll view like 
this :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT9g-JdW6ms&feature=youtu.be

how create that header ?

Comment: i couldnt find any library until now :(

Comment: One of the possibilities is to use CoordinatorLayout and put the HorizontalScrollView with layout_scrollFlag property set to 'scroll|snap' in the AppBarLayout